# Ruby Method not Returning False within a Recursion Block

Tags: ruby

I'm doing a ruby challenge that I found on rubeque.com.  Here are the instructions:

Instructions:
Write a method #r_empty? that returns true if a hash and its subhashes are empty or false if there is a value in the hash.

My Answer:

```
class Hash
    def r_empty?
        def recurse(h)
            h.each {|key, value|
                value.is_a?(Hash) ? recurse(value) : 
            if (value!=nil && value!="")
                #puts value
                return false
            end
            }
        return true             
        end
    recurse(self)
    end
end
```

Test:

```
a = {:ruby => "", :queue => ""}    
b = {:ruby => {:version => {:one => {"nine" => ""}, "two" => "=^.^="}}, 
:html => ""}    
c = {:pets => {:dogs => {:my => {"niko" => ""}, "ollie" => ""}}, :cats => 
nil, :mice => ""}    
d = {a: "", b: :two, c: ""}
```

Answers:

```
a.r_empty?, true    
b.r_empty?, false    
c.r_empty?, true    
d.r_empty?, false    
({}.r_empty?), true
```

Using this code, I was able to get the right answer for 4 out of the 5 tests.  My method returns TRUE for b.r_empty? ... I do notice that if I uncomment out #puts value, "=^.^=" is printed out for b.r_empty? ... So the if statement is being executed, but ultimately false is not returned.  I'm still a ruby novice so I will gladly appreciate any advice and guidance towards the right topics i should go over for this challenge.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: My bad, Class is capitalized for some reason.. so it's supposed to be class Hash {..rest of code..}, let me know if there's any more problems

Answer (score 1):

Although it's cool to define a method inside another (I did not know this was possibly actually) the method can be simplified quite a bit:

```
class Hash
  def r_empty?
    !values.any? do |val|
       val.is_a?(Hash) ? !val.r_empty? : (val && val != "")
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure exactly the problem is with your original code, however I think the `recurse(value)` is effectively being discarded.

By the way, in terms of style I recommend only using a ternary for single-line expressions and also being diligent about consistent indentation.

Comment: Awesome, it works! Could you give me a quick overview of the logic behind your code?  I'll also actively google and look up the docs for the methods you used.

Comment: The only methods I used that aren't in the original are [Hash#values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-i-values) (returns an array, similar to [Hash#keys](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Hash.html#method-i-keys)) and [Enumerable#any?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F).

Comment: To understand it you can kind of read it like pseudocode: `Are none of the values either: a. hashes containing some non-blank value or b. non-blank values?`. Also keep in mind that Rails comes with a method [Object#blank?](https://apidock.com/rails/Object/blank%3F) which covers this nil-or-empty-string use-case.

Comment: `!values.any?` could be simplified to [`values.none?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-none-3F)

Comment: @maxpleaner: it is not actually possible to define methods _inside_ one another. The syntax is valid, yes, but the inner method will be defined on the same scope as the outer method. It will not be hidden in the outer method (unlike in some other languages)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev but only after the method in which they are defined is called. You can also define singleton methods for an instance in this fashion as well

Comment: I have another question about @maxpleaner 's code. Why are we using `(!)` for `!val.r_empty?` The way I'm understanding that line of code is if the value is a hash execute recursion, else return true or false depending on if the value is non-nil or empty string.  To execute recursion wouldn't `val.r_empty?` suffice?

Comment: @StevenLian you're checking whether or not _any_ of the sub-hashes are _non empty_. Non empty = `!val.r_empty?`.